# How to debug AWS API Getway "Internal message error"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-api-gateway

I have created an API Gateway linked to a (tested and working) Lambda function.

I get a

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

when I try to access to it, but I have no logs about it, even creating and attaching a log stream.

How can I have a more precise error?

Comment: Did you set up the proxy for the integration? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource

Comment: I use an HTTP API, so I cannot setup a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a trace using X-Ray and you can see where along the path it is failing. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-using-xray-maps.html